# mySQL: kill all processes except one process id

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to kill all mySQL processes at once, **except** for one process id?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Why do even you need to kill the processes?

Comment: linux, i have one long running query, and want all others to be ended on command, but not that one.

Comment: do you mean OS process id's or mysql connection id's ?

Comment: hey i think it is a great question and answer from Johan. at least you can learn something from it, why the downvote !  :>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the information_schema table for that, its a bit of a hassle but it works ;)

```
mysql> select concat('KILL ',id,';') from information_schema.processlist
where id != '1234' into outfile '/tmp/foo.txt';

mysql> source /tmp/foo.txt;
```